# Jasmine tests always failing in RxJS 7 when using toBeObservable()

Tags: rxjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine-marbles

I've updated my dependencies and am now confronted with this error message:

```
DEPRECATION: The matcher factory for "toBeObservable" accepts custom equality testers, but this parameter will no longer be passed in a future release. See <https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/upgrading_to_Jasmine_4.0#matchers-cet> for details.

Error: Expected $[0].notification to be a kind of Object, but was Notification({ kind: 'N', value: true, error: undefined, hasValue: true }).
            at <Jasmine>
            at toBeObservableComparer (node_modules/jasmine-marbles/es6/index.js:80:1)
            at <Jasmine>
```

The test is very simple:

```js
const expected = cold('a', {a: true});
expect(new BehaviorSubject(true)).toBeObservable(expected);
```

It might have to do something with the deprecation notice, but I'm just using `toBeObservable()` from latest version of the `jasmine-marbles` package and can't see a custom parameter. Also I don't understand why `Notification` isn't a kind of `Object`.

Versions:

- rxjs: 7.5.2
- jasmine-core: 4.0.0
- jasmine-marbles: 0.8.4
- karma-jasmine: 4.0.1

The script works on rxjs 6.6.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the new documentation shows the new expectObservable:

```
expectObservable(new BehaviorSubject(true).asObservable()).toBe(expected);
```

Check out the documentation here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/testing/marble-testing.md#marble-syntax

Answer (score 0):

jasmine-marbles version => 0.9.0 supports RxJS 7.x

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-marbles